# New joiners - Hyphenated?

Tags: hyphens

When referring to people that have joined a company, would the term *new-joiners* be hyphenated or not?

My understanding is that the word is a compound noun where "new" is the adjective and "joiners" is the noun, forming a single word meaning it **should** be hyphenated.

For example:

> We’ve been working on a project to help welcome new joiners.

You wouldn't refer to someone as an old joiner, or just a joiner.

"new-joiner" or "new joiner"

Comment: We generally wouldn't call new people at a company "joiners" - they're "new employees".

Comment: *My understanding is that the word is a compound noun where "new" is the adjective and "joiners" is the noun, forming a single word meaning it should be hyphenated.* That's not correct.  "New joiners" isn't a single "compound noun" any more than "red apple" is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule compound words are not hyphenated when one of them is being used as a noun but they are hyphenated if the compound word is an adjective. e.g.

> We’ve been working on a project to help welcome new (adj) joiners (noun).

but

> We’ve been working on a project to help welcome the new-joiner (adj) group.

This link [Hyphens](https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp) provides some useful advice on the use of hyphenated compound words, as well as other uses of hypens.